# probability that the student will correctly answer exactly 9 questions

Tags: probability

> A multiple choice examination has $10$ questions, each of which has $4$ possible answers.Suppose that for each question a student knows the correct answer with probability $0.8$ and guesses with probability $0.2$. Find the probability that the student will correctly answer exactly $9$ questions?

My solution:

P(Exactly 9 correct answers)= $10$ * $(0.8)^9$ * $0.2$
The given solution answer is $0.3474$.
How should I solve this?

Comment: If the idea is that the student guesses if he doesn't know the answer, then the chance of answering any question correctly is $P(\text{knows}) + P(\text{guesses correctly}) = 0.8 + 0.2 \times 0.25$. Does that help?

Comment: This is much clear. Thanks.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff Why 0.25 and not 0.5 ? For example: $0.8 + 0.2 \times \underbrace{0.5}_{\uparrow} = 0.81$.

Comment: Because there are 4 options and each has equal probability.

Comment: @roang Got it !!!. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic approach.** The student *knows* the correct answer with probability $0.8$ and guesses with probability $0.2$—presumably, they guess each of the four possible answers with equal likelihood.  Therefore, the probability that they *submit* the correct answer is greater than $0.8$.  How much more is it?  Use that value instead of $0.8$ in the binomial expansion, and you should obtain the right answer.

Comment: P(Submit right ans) = P(Knows ans)P(Submit right answer|knows ans) + P(does n't know ans)P(Submit right answer|does n't know ans) = 0.8 · 1 + 0.2 · 0.25 = 0.8 + 0.05 = 0.85.
Is this correct?

Comment: @roang: Why don't you try using that value and seeing if you get the right answer? :-)

Comment: :) Thanks. That was the right answer.